# Phaser 3 typescript player.alive is undefined

Tags: typescript, ionic4, phaser-framework

I am trying to add phaser 3 games to my ionic 4 application using this method found on github (https://github.com/write2sv/ionic4-phaser3-template/commits/master).

This means rewriting my games in typescript, and some other changes. one big issue I am coming across is defining my player as alive which is the first if statement in my `update()`. it just returns undefined and I do not understand why. Can anyone help me on how to get around this?

Here is how I define my player:

```
 player = this.physics.add.sprite(window.innerWidth / 2, 
 window.innerHeight - 100, 'ship');
 player.setOrigin(.5, .5);
 //this.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.Arcade);
 player.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.Arcade;
```

I have tried using .enable but I get the following error :`Property 'enable' does not exist on type 'ArcadePhysics'`

Another possible cause:

```
 this.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.Arcade);
```

I get the following error with startSystem Property `'startSystem' does not exist on type 'ArcadePhysics'`. By adding a physics sprite I thought I would get around both these errors but no.

My guess is I should be using `game.physics`, when I do I get game as undefined. This is because of the unusual setup seen in the GitHub link provided. Any pointers would be great as I am completely lost!